# Why this one has error and how can i correct it?

Tags: c#

```
public void FilenameHasWord(string filename, string word)
    {   
        Boolean red = filename.Contains(word);
        if (red == true)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(" the filename contains the word");
           if (red == false)  
           {
        MessageBox.Show(" the filename does not contain the word");
           }


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FilenameHasWord();
        string filename = "textBox1.Text";
        string word = "textBox2.Text";
    }
```

Comment: *What* error does it have? (What's the exact message?) *Where* exactly does the error occur? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: `if( red)` and `if( ! red)`, please.

Comment: or better in this case `if(red){...}else{....}`

Answer (score 3):

A bit of confusion here, I think you want:

```
public void FilenameHasWord(string filename, string word)
{   

    Boolean red = filename.Contains(word);
    if (red == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" the filename contains the word");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" the filename does not contain the word");
    }
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string filename = textBox1.Text;
    string word = textBox2.Text;
    FilenameHasWord(filename, word);
 }
```

First, your test with Contains return TRUE or FALSE so an if/else statement to show the result, not an `if(false)` inside the block of `if(true)` then, when you call the function you should pass TWO string arguments. These two string arguments should be the content of the textboxes and this content is expressed writing the variables representing the TextBoxes followed by the property `Text` without double quotes.

Now, re-reading your messageboxes text, I have a doubt. What do you mean for `the filename (does not) contains the word`?. The `string.Contains` method checks if a string contains another string.

[string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't try to use the instance string supposing that it is the name of a file and doesn't check if that supposed file contains the word passed as argument.

Comment: damn, you just beat me to it! :) +1

Comment: +1 I would write just `if(red)` alone

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes it's enough and more concise. I leave it just to be clear for the OP

Answer (score 1):

Your function `FilenameHasWord()` requires two parameters. You are not passing any when you call it.
Also, you are declaring two strings that contain "textBox1.Text" and "textBox2.Text" respectively, perhaps you need to remove those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this - it resolves:

1. Issue with not reading textbox values correctly
2. FilenameHasWord method requires 2 params
3. Braces not matched correctly

   ```
   public void FilenameHasWord(string filename, string word)
   {   
       if (filename.Contains(word))
       {
           MessageBox.Show(" the filename contains the word");
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show(" the filename does not contain the word");
       }
    }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string filename = textBox1.Text;
       string word = textBox2.Text;
       FilenameHasWord(filename,word);

   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

**1.** You need to assign the values inside the `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` controls. but in your code you are assigning TextBox1 and TextBox2 as strings.

**2.** You need to assign those values to `FilenameHasWord()` function as it takes two arguments.

Try This:

```
public void FilenameHasWord(string filename, string word)
{   

    Boolean red = filename.Contains(word);
    if (red == true)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(" the filename contains the word");    
    }

     if (red == false)
     {
      MessageBox.Show(" the filename does not contain the word");
     }
 }
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string filename = textBox1.Text;
    string word = textBox2.Text;
    FilenameHasWord(filename,word);

}
```

Comment: @Downvoter : please explain the mistake here.

Comment: I don't understand why you're being downvoted - this is one of the mistakes in the code. There is another, but since the OP didn't specify what error he's talking about, this is just as true an answer as another.

Comment: FilenameHasWord() takes 2 parameters. This will not compile

Comment: @geedubb: i have edited with complete code now Thanks

Comment: Still you have a call to FilenameHasWord without params :-)

Comment: @Steve: sorry i forgot to remove te statement, Thanks